# Array element without index when var_dump()?

Tags: php, arrays

When I `var_dump($_SESSION['qty'])`, I got this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(1) [""]=> int(2) }
```

May I know what this `[""]=> int(2)` means? Basically I do this to the array:

```
    $key3 = array_intersect($key1, $key2);
    if ($key3 != NULL )
   {$_SESSION['qty'][$key3[0]]= $_SESSION['qty'][$key3[0]]+$_POST['qty'];}
```

For some reason, sometimes it gives me this `[""]=> int(2)`.

EDIT:if

```
($key3 != NULL && current($key3) !=NULL  )
{   $_SESSION['qty'][current($key3)]= $_SESSION['qty']current($key3)]+$_POST['qty'];}
```

somehow i still get the same problem after checking for nulll

Comment: `$key[0]` is an empty string in this case.  Chase down why.

Comment: As far as I know, it means you have a null key.

Comment: you can have an empty string as the key

Comment: does this mean my if condition isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [`arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are maps that associate *values* to *keys*. The documentation explains it clearly:

> The key can either be an [`integer`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) or a [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). The value can be of any type.

Accordingly, the empty string (`''`) is a valid array key. More, the documentation also provides the most possible reason why you get it as a key in your array:

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - [`Null`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key `null` will actually be stored under `""`.

Back to your code, it seems `$key[0]` is not set (either `$key` is not set or it is an empty string).